# Find a product of cyclic groups isomorphic to Z/20

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, cyclic-decomposition

I have to decompose the multiplicative group Z/20 into a product of cyclic groups. Now the order of Z/20 is $\phi(20) = 8$ right? So by the fundamental theorem of abelian groups I factorize $8$ into $2^3$ and hence Z/20 is isomorphic to either Z/8, Z/4 x Z/2 or Z/2 x Z/2 x Z/2. Is that correct or have I made a mistake somewhere? Any tips are welcome

Comment: Do you mean the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/20)^*$?

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. You should not say things like "the order of $\mathbb{Z}/20$ is $8$", because this is not true. Instead, please be precise, i.e. "the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/20)^\times$ is $\phi(20) = 8$"!

Comment: @rogerl Yes that one. I just wasn't sure with the notation of it

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thank you, I will keep that in mind

Comment: You might also have a typo: did you mean $\mathbb{Z}/4 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/4 \times \mathbb{Z}/4$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/20)^\times\cong(\mathbb Z/4)^\times\times(\mathbb Z/5)^\times\cong\mathbb Z/2\times\mathbb Z/4$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Oh yea that was a mistake actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have confused $\mathbb Z_{20}$ and $\mathbb Z_{20}^\times$.  The former has order $20$, the latter $\varphi(20)=8$.

Let's say you are talking about the former.  Then you can use CRT to write it as a product of cyclic groups.  Then $\mathbb Z_{20}\cong\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_5$.

---

On the other hand, for the slightly more difficult problem,  $\mathbb Z_{20}^×\cong (\mathbb Z_4×\mathbb Z_5)^×\cong\mathbb Z_4^××\mathbb Z_5^×\cong\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_4$, because the group of units functor respects products.